# How can I solve quadratic modular equations?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I looked at this topic [How can I solve quadratic equations using modular arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261896/how-can-i-solve-quadratic-equations-using-modular-arithmetic), but it still didn't answer my question.

$$n^2 + n + 8 \equiv 0 \pmod {18}$$

According to the discussion mentioned earlier, we need to complete the square and then solve it. Also, if the linear term is odd, then we can add a multiple of the modulus to make it even. This only works if the modulus is odd. However, in this case modulus is even. How do I solve this equation?

Comment: With such a small modulus, you can simply search.  As the modulus is not prime, there could be  (and are) more than $2$ solutions.

Comment: More abstractly, you can factor $18=2\times 3^2$, solve the problem $\pmod 2$ and $\pmod 9$ and then combine those via the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: **Hint**: $4n^2+4n+1=(2n+1)^2$